# Log stacktrace and continue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

I have a scenario when i need to log strack trace instead of throwing it and continue the execution, since the try and catch are in a loop.

How i can do this in c#?

```
try
{}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
log(ex);
 //this should continue 
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Because if you only log in the catch block, it will continue as you've caught and "handled" the exception.

Comment: you can use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) or just `List<string>` and add each time stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can use nlog to monitor the exceptions in a log file.
or you can log your errors to the event viewer of you hosting machine.